# How to set a JSpinner to be transparent (not opaque)

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

While trying to create a custom `LookandFeel` and needing to set a `JSpinner` to be non-opaque, I was not able to find the answer anywhere on StackOverflow, but found a close answer [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2516906?start=0&tstart=0):

The code should actually be something like this:

```
spinner.setOpaque(false);
spinner.getEditor().setOpaque(false);
((JSpinner.DefaultEditor)spinner.getEditor()).getTextField().setOpaque(false);
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Are you stil need a help or you already found the answer?

Comment: A `JSpinner` is made of several components - buttons and text field. If they are all transparent you won't see it. Do you want just the text field to be transparent?